# Setting multiple divs by width percent to fill parent div next to each other

Tags: html, css, width

If you have multiple divs next to each other in a parent div with a fixed width and the child divs width set as a percentage of the fixed parent with, sometimes the child divs aren't all visible on the same line nevertheless the sum of width percentages of the child divs is 100%.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="child" style="width:51.5%;">1</div>
<div class="child" style="width:0.58333333333333%;">2</div>
<div class="child" style="width:21.666666666667%;">3</div>
<div class="child" style="width:0.56944444444444%;">4</div>
<div class="child" style="width:15%;">5</div>
<div class="child" style="width:0.23611111111111%;">6</div>
<div class="child" style="width:6.7361111111111%;">7</div>
<div class="child" style="width:0.69444444444444%;">8</div>
<div class="child" style="width:2.3611111111111%;">9</div>
<div class="child" style="width:0.47222222222222%;">10</div>
<div class="child" style="width:0.18055555555556%;">11</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
float:left;
width:850px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.child{
border:1px solid red;
float:left;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color:blue;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4gvgqkkc/3/

Any idea?

Comment: Sub-pixel rounding is managed differently by different browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove property `border` from child.because it is increasing the width of children.
Also add `margin:0;padding:0;` to child. If you add `margin padding` ,they will increase the children size. decrease % width if border is needed that it can allocate additional border

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/koqb08a0/)

Comment: I use the css box-sizing method so the given div width is including the border width and I want to use a border.

Comment: If you want border then calculate percentage width such a way that after adding 1px+1px=2px border it become equal to width to your present width;

Comment: Let width is 10px,you declared. now if u add 1px border then it goes to 10+1+1=12px;so give % size that it reach to 10 after adding border;that is declare width=8px;then after adding border it reaches to 10px.ok? so use % of 8px not 10px.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the total width of the child divs are greater than 100% and its border are additional. Adjust this by reducing width of divs. Then they will appear in single line